# Catch event of auto_shrink in SQL Server Log?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, shrink

I am aware of the disadvantages of `AUTO_SHRINK` being configured on SQL Server databases. Recently, in a new environment, I discovered several production servers with the Auto Shrink option turned on.

Now, before I change this configuration, I wonder: Since the auto_shrink event starts at 25% unused space I wonder if and/or when this is actually happening on the SQL Servers. I  tried to find the relevant SQL-Event-Logfile entries. I started manual shrinking on test databases but there is no Event-Log entry showing up.

Does anyone know how to find out when shrinking has happened within the latest days or weeks on a SQL Server?

Comment: Are you looking for shrink information in SQl Server errorlog ? Or in traces, where ?

Comment: @Shanky whereever I can find em! I would like to finde an answer to the question: Did auto shrinks happen in the latest past and influence the performance?

Comment: Did you wnet through http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/05/13/when-was-the-last-time-a-database-or-file-was-shrunk.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354455/is-there-are-a-way-to-check-the-last-time-a-shrink-operation-was-done-on-a-sql-s its just matter of good search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get the details accordingly from the default trace ([read here for more](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/)) , depending upon its retention out there from query below:

```
DECLARE @TracePath NVARCHAR(1000);

-- Get the file path for the default trace
SELECT    @TracePath = 
        REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
        CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 1000)) + 'log.trc'
FROM     sys.traces
WHERE     is_default = 1;

-- Query to get auto growth and shrink event from the default trace
SELECT     EventName = te.[name],
    tr.ServerName,
    tr.DatabaseName,
    tr.[FileName],
    FilePath = sf.[filename],
    Duration_in_ms = tr.Duration/1000,
    FileGrowth_in_mb = (tr.IntegerData*8)/1024,
    tr.StartTime,
    tr.EndTime
FROM     sys.fn_trace_gettable(@TracePath, DEFAULT) tr
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events te
        ON tr.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
    INNER JOIN sys.sysaltfiles sf
        ON tr.[FileName] = sf.[name]
WHERE     te.name in (
        'Data File Auto Grow',
        'Log File Auto Grow',
        'Data File Auto Shrink',
        'Log File Auto Shrink')
ORDER BY tr.StartTime DESC;
```

Also, you can view the same by Standard reports section:

1) Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

2) On the object explorer highlight the database whose auto shrink event you want to check and make a right click

3) Select Reports and then Standard Reports. Then select Disk Usage

4) It will open a report on the screen and if there is any recent auto grow and/or autoshrink event on that database, you should be able to see the “Data/Log Files Autogrow/Autoshrink Events” section.

Answer (score 2):

Pls see [this link](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/find-who-ran-shrinkfile/) :

To summarize (and this worked for me) :

Find out the location of your default trace file using :

`SELECT * FROM fn_trace_getinfo(default);`

Then use that to query your default trace file :

```
SELECT top 10 
    TextData,
    HostName,
    ApplicationName,
    LoginName, 
    StartTime  
 FROM 
 [fn_trace_gettable]('C:\MSSQL\Log\log_1110.trc', DEFAULT) 
 WHERE TextData LIKE '%SHRINK%';
```

You can see entries there for operations like `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` etc.